# PreferenceActivity with multiple preference files

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

The way to use a preference file (instead of the default shared preferences) in PreferenceActivity is as follows:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
         prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("my_preferences");
         prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

In this example we use the Shared Preference named "my_preferences".
But how would we use more than one custom preference in the same PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the names of your preference files and while retriving the preferences, mention the name of that file which you want to access in getSharedPreferences().

Here I declare two file names : PrefFile and PrefFileNEW; then I pass the respective names to the getSharedPreference() while retrieving the preferences.

```
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME_NEW = "PrefFileNEW";
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
{
//access your preferences here
}

SharedPreferences preferences_new = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME_NEW, MODE_PRIVATE);

{
//access your preferences_new here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is probably going to work in an ordinary Activity. I'm starting to believe that in PreferenceActivity however what I want to do is not possible.

Comment: Could you please share why you are going for PreferenceActivity specifically instead of a usual Activity ?

Comment: No big reason other than convenience.

Comment: Well, in that case you would have to choose between convenience and whatever you are trying to implement, as you can pretty much do the same in a normal Activity by using the code I gave.